# Symfony2 doctrine relation data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have some little error with doctrine mapping . I have genarate entities and mapping data from console , and when i trying to get related column data it sets to null and i did not know why

Entites :

TasksCaregories :

```
/**
     * @var \PhpTasksBundle\Entity\Tasks
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PhpTasksBundle\Entity\Tasks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="category_id", unique=true)
     * })
     */
    private $id;
```

Tasks :

```
/**
     * @var \PhpTasksBundle\Entity\TasksCategories
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PhpTasksBundle\Entity\TasksCategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $category;
```

Controller :

```
$tasks = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('PhpTasksBundle:Tasks')
            ->findAll();
```

View:

{{ dump(tasks) }}

and i get empty "name" column in related array .

But i need to get not hull name from category :( Please somebody help

Comment: Why is Tasks a OneToOne relationship with category ?

Comment: that was generate from console . I dont know :( . Must be one-to-many

Comment: The relationship between your entities is [ManyToMany](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional). It is up to you if it is unidirectional or bidirectional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good for the relation ManyToOne between Taks -> TasksCategories (it means that one categorie may have many differents tasks (absolutely logic):

```
/**
 * @var \PhpTasksBundle\Entity\TasksCategories
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PhpTasksBundle\Entity\TasksCategories")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $category;
```

So, conversely, the relation TasksCategories -> Tasks could be : OneToMany or ManyToMany according to your need.

For example : you want that one Task could be attached to many Categories (ManyToMany), if not, one Task -> just one Categorie (OneToMany). I hope clear for you.